# How to merge 2 rows into 1 row in Excel file using UiPath

Tags: excel, uipath

I want to merge the 2 rows into 1 row in Excel via UiPath, if you need the example you can refer to the below. Appreciate your help for this question. Thanks.

This one is input
[image: This is the original Excel data]

This is the output I require
[image: This is what I want to show in my excel file]

Comment: Not sure what you want?

Answer (score 0):

In order to do you need to use the below activities:

1. "Read Range" to read the data from Excel and store the output in a data table
2. Now use "Assign" activities to join(StringJoin function) the row values in the desired format for example Row1, Row2 and store that value in a variable
3. "Write Cell" activities to write the Value in the desired section/row number/column number.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you want, you can do below:

dt = original dt

create variable lstColumn as string

you can use below exact code in Invoke Code activity with argument of dt and dt2 (both as In/Out)

```
Dim cntr As Integer
cntr = 0
dt2 = dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(rw) String.IsNullOrEmpty(rw(0).ToSTring)).CopyToDataTable
For Each col as DataColumn In dt2.Columns.Cast(Of DataColumn)
cntr = cntr+1
col.ColumnName = "Column" & cntr    
Next col
dt.AsEnumerable().where(Function(rw) Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(rw(0).ToString)).CopyToDataTable
```

in sequence follow this

```
lstColumn = (dt.Columns.Count + 65).ToString
```

use write range activity with parameters:

```
path> C:\Temp\Test123.xlsx
sheet> "Sheet1"
startcell> "A1"
AddHeaders> True datatable> dt.AsEnumerable().Where(Function(rw) 
String.IsNullOrEmpty(rw(0).ToSTring))
```

again use write range activity with parameters:

```
path[C:\Temp\Test123.xlsx]
sheet = "Sheet1"
startcell = lstCOlumn & "1"
AddHeaders = True
datatable = dt2
```